# Ubuntu 14.04.5 how to upgrade from to new kernel

Tags: kernel

The latest Ubuntu 14.04.5 installation comes with a new 4.4 kernel.  I have an existing Ubuntu 14.04 VM that is at 14.04.5 release but it still is using the 3.13 kernel.  The kernel doesn't get updated.  Is there a way to upgrade to the 4.4 kernel?  I don't want to move to Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks.

Cathy

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try a little utility called ukuu. (Universal kernel update utility?). You can install any kernel, and check to see if you can update

You will have to add the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

And then install:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Please note that this will install a mainline kernel